# Setting paypal IPN url programmatically

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Can I have paypal IPN redirect to a unique URL for each transaction?

For instance,

transaction 1 - www.WebSite.com/Listener/1

transaction 2 - www.WebSite.com/Listener/2

transaction 3 - www.WebSite.com/Listener/3

I know which field to set programmatically, but documentation points out that only one URL can be used and I am not sure if above examples are also included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="notify_url" value="URLspecificToThisTransaction">
```

"PayPal posts HTML FORM variables to a program at a URL you specify. You can specify this URL either in your account profile or with the notify_url variable on each transaction"

This should override the setting you have on your account.  See this document for further information.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, but that is related only to redirect after payment. I am interested in IPN url. Think it is called notify_url. I know I can set it but not sure if I can change it for each transaction like return parameter, or it has to be the same as on account.

Comment: Oops!  Updated answer.  I think you should be good although this is an interesting use case.

Comment: Thanks, well, guess I'll just have to test it and see. Will update answer if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I originally misread your email.  I've worked with Paypal before an I think I automatically read your problem to be what mine was.

Comment: Tested it out and it works. Each transaction can have different IPN listener.